# How to run MSTest test cases in a particular order using vstest command line tool

Tags: selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2019, mstest

```
start vstest.console.exe MyProject1.UI.MSTest.dll /testcasefilter:TestCategory=Category1
```

I have a number of MSTest test cases that have been decorated with `[TestMethod, TestCategory("Category1")]` in the same project. Is there away i can tell `vstest` to run the tests is specific order, say like tell it to run testcase **A** first and then run testcase **y** last?

Am using VS 2019.

Answer (score 1):

If possible concider the option to re-write the tests so they are not dependent on execution order. This article have a some more details and tips on using playlist.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/order-unit-tests?pivots=mstest